# Two-twistors formulation vs twistors formulation

Tags: field-theory, supersymmetry, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, twistor

I have seen in some research work that the classic formulation using twistors (introduced by Penrose) is replaced with a formulation that considers two-twistors.

For example the [linking](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09557) article says that the combined result of some articles can be summarized as: "a two-twister formulation of classical mechanics of a zero spin-particle of mass $m$ in $AdS_D$ is possible for $D = 5$, with a known action, and it is also possible for $D = 4, 7$, but only if $m = 0$."

I do not understand what this consists of, that is the fact that the formulation with two-twistors leads to this result, it could (for example) instead be that the formulation with "classic" twistors allows different and/or discordant results, such as $m$ not zero also for $D = 4, 7$?

My question is not specific to the link article, it is just an example, my question is:
Why use two-twistors instead of twistors? Is it possible that using both formulations I can find different results? or the use of one formulation instead of the other is only for "convenience" of calculation, but the results must be in agreement? So, in the specific case also with the formulation of the "classic" twistors I will have $m = 0$ for $D = 4, 7$, as obtained with the two-twistors?

Comment: Haven't gone through the link but in general you will need minimum two "classic" twistors to create massive states. These two-twistors will have internal symmetries which can be used to describe various aspects of leptons and weak-interactions. Search for twistor particle programme.

Comment: @KP99 - Thank you very much for your answer.. but in your opinion, what does it mean to get  "a two-twistor formulation of the classical mechanics of a zero spin-particle of mass $m$ in $AdS_D$ is possible for $D = 5$, with a known action, and it is possible also for $D = 4, 7$, but only if $m = 0$" ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not yet familiar with twistors in higher dimensions. Hope someone else can clarify this question.